# Appcelerator Titanium ld.exe: error: cannot find -lkroll-v8

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I can't build my module for Appcelerator Titanium after update to SDK v6.0.2.GA (all was fine with version 5.x.x).

In log I see many errors "undefined reference to 'v8::...".
Full version of log you can find [here](http://pasted.co/fbea450c)

Before that I received "ld.exe: error: cannot find -lkroll-v8" error and tried to fix that by copying of libkroll-v8.so file from previous titanium SDK version. Original log you can find [here](http://pasted.co/7468c330).

I've tried to redownload last SDK - no luck, error still here.

Comment: which android NDK version are you using? NDK r12b? Try to run `ti clean` in the folder and try this [jira ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24164?focusedCommentId=403746&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-403746)

Comment: @miga I've tried with r11b, r12b  (one and the same problem) and r14 (as I understand, appcelerator doesn't support this version yet). 

About ti clean. I use Appcelerator Studio, as I understand project -> clean perform the same action. I'm not able to run ti from a command line (it's possible that I need to add some folder to the path variable, but I don't know which one).

Comment: yes, the project clean should do the same. If you want to use the CLI later on you could install all the tools via `npm install -g titanium alloy appcelerator` which should be already installed. That sould make the tools globally available and you can run `ti` or `appc ti` in your project folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1.Change build.properties (Latest NDK)

> titanium.platform=/Library/Application
>   Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.GA/android
>   android.platform=/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23
>   google.apis=/Library/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-23
>   android.ndk=/Documents/r12b

2. Delete the **build/generated/jni** folder (if it exists)
3. Delete the **libs/armeabi** folder (if it exists) and remove **armeabi** from the manifest
4. Rebuild the module using **appc run -p android --build-only**

Note: I have tested this issue with latest SDK 6.0.2.GA, it's working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! After your advice, I found modules rebuild guide for titanium SDK 6.0.0. Maybe it will be helpful for someone else. 

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+SDK+6.0.0+Changes